# array inside array in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to put the integer value of $QQ array into presenter array, no luck please help.

```
$QQ = $this->MAudio->getAllAudio();

$presenter = $this->Profile_model->getProfile($QQ['a_presenter_id']);

$data['name'] = $presenter['name'];
```

Comment: The above code looks fine, check your functions

Answer (score 0):

I think issue is with $this->MAudio->getAllAudio(); I think u have return Object now u got to convert that object into value by calling row() or row_array() or result() or result_array()

Try this code

```
$QQ = $this->MAudio->getAllAudio()->row_array();

$presenter = $this->Profile_model->getProfile($QQ['a_presenter_id']);

$data['name'] = $presenter['name'];
```

Comment: getAllAudio() returns array not object

Comment: humm.. well in that case check if the structure of return array contain `a_presenter_id` using print_r($QQ), if it doesn't it mean something wrong with query